# Oracle 12c Database Configuration Assistant: Error

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, windows-server-2016

Had this error while installing Oracle DB 12.1.0.2 Enterprise (64-bit) on a VM with Windows Server 2016 (64 bit OS) with all the Hard/Software requirements. The installer file was unzipped in the same parent folder but I changed the folder name to: Oracle Database 12c Release 1 64 Enterprise (12.1.0.2.0).

```
Error while executing   
"C:/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/dbmssml.sql". Refer to 
"C:/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/dbmssml0.log" for more details. Error in 
Process: C:/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/perl/bin/perl.exe
```

The dbmssml0.log file is empty. Then the installer threw a:

[INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.

Cause - The plug-in failed in its perform method
Action - Refer to the logs or contact Oracle Support Services.
Log File Location
C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions2020-08-03_03-57-18PM.log

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3315t23qxuxlqh7/installActions2020-08-03_03-57-18PM.log?dl=0) is the installation log.

I'm a new Oracle user and I'm not sure how to read the log or locate the error, please let me know if need any additional details. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Heber

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12.1 is not certified on Windows 2016, per the [Database Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/reqs.htm#NTDBI2698). But [Oracle 12.2 is supported on Windows 2016](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntdbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-microsoft-windows.html#GUID-E3991846-D2D7-4D71-9F8F-F90996F046B5).

There's a big difference between 12.1 and 12.2. Make sure you're always looking at the right version of the documentation.